# Class.asSubclass with multiple bounded types and unchecked cast

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a class which is generified with the type `<T extends Enum<T> & Runnable>`. I have a member variable `Class<T> bar` which I set by the class name: `t = (Class<T>) Class.forName(name)`. This gives me an unchecked cast warning.

Normally, using [asSubclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) can be used in similar situations, but since `T` has multiple bounds, I'm not able to use it without getting a compiler warning:

```
//This is type safe, but I still get an unchecked cast warning
t = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Enum.class).asSubclass(Runnable.class);
```

Can I get rid of this warning in any way, without using `@SupressedWarning("unchecked")`?

Full example:

```
public class Example<T extends Enum<T> & Runnable> {
    Class<T> t;

    Example(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        t = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Enum.class).asSubclass(Runnable.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//This is type safe, but I still get an unchecked cast warning
t = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Enum.class).asSubclass(Runnable.class);
```

Whoa, slow down a second!  Is that actually true?  No it's not!  All you've done is establish that the class matching the passed-in name is both a `Runnable` and an `Enum`, not that it is actually `T`.  You've only validated the bounds.  Imagine we had classes `T1` and `T2`:

```
package foo;
public enum T1 implements Runnable {
    ;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}

package foo;
public enum T2 implements Runnable {
    ;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Then this works fine, but is obviously not type safe:

```
Example<T1> example = new Example<T1>("foo.T2");
Class<T1> t1Clazz = example.t; //uh oh...
```

This isn't a problem of multiple bounds either.  You'd have the same problem with only one bound.

As @sp00m mentions, the real solution is probably to pass in `Class<T>` here.

### Edit

If, on the other hand, `T` was only needed *internally* (i.e. to specify the multiple bounds) and need not actually be exposed, then another option is to maintain the class in two separate references.  For example:

```
Class<? extends Runnable> runnableClass;
Class<? extends Enum> enumClass;

Example(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    runnableClass = clazz.asSubclass(Runnable.class);
    enumClass = clazz.asSubclass(Enum.class);
}
```

That's because, without the type parameter, there are very few circumstances where you could actually take *advantage* of the knowledge that it's an `enum` and a `Runnable` at the same time.  If you create an instance of the class, you need to assign it to a variable/field of type `Runnable` or `Enum`; you can't do both.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply can't... The best solution in my opinion would be to pass the `Class<T> clazz` directly as parameter rather than its `String name`.

Comment: That's not always possible. What if the class is a command-line argument?